# faço a verificação de 2 datas mais está persistindo

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-5.2

possuo um formulário, e antes de salvar quero que faça uma verificação que no caso seria de duas datas. Só que quando é feita uma verificação lança uma Mensagem até aí OK. Mais acaba aparecendo outra referente que conseguiu persistir e acaba salvando no banco.

Segue meu codigo.

Meu Bean

```
public void salvar() {
    try {
        this.servicoService.salvar(servico);
        Messages.addGlobalInfo("Serviço salvo com sucesso!");
        limpar();
    } catch (NegocioException e) {
        Messages.addGlobalError(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Meu Service

```
public void salvar(Servico servico) throws NegocioException {
    try {
         if (servico.getDiaServico().after(servico.getDiaGarantia())) {
            FacesUtil.addWarnMessage("A data do serviço, não pode ser maior do que a data da garantia.");
        }
        servicoDAO.salvar(servico);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new NegocioException("Não foi possível salvar o cliente!");
    }
}[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema está aqui:

```
try {
    if (servico.getDiaServico().after(servico.getDiaGarantia())) {
        FacesUtil.addWarnMessage("A data do serviço, não pode ser maior do que a data da garantia.");
    }
    servicoDAO.salvar(servico);
}
```

Do jeito que está, caso as datas sejam inválidas ele apenas inclui uma mensagem de warning e continua o fluxo normal. Nesse caso, o próximo passo do "fluxo normal" é `servicoDAO.salvar(servico)`.

O que você pode fazer é, logo depois de adicionar a mensagem de erro, lançar uma `Exception`. Ex:

```
try {
    if (servico.getDiaServico().after(servico.getDiaGarantia())) {
        FacesUtil.addWarnMessage("A data do serviço, não pode ser maior do que a data da garantia.");
        throw new NegocioException("Não foi possível salvar o cliente!")
    }
    servicoDAO.salvar(servico);
}
```

Dessa forma você garante que o "fluxo normal" será interrompido pela `Exception`.

---

Outra coisa, da forma que disse as `Exception`s serão "duplicadas" por que você captura qualquer tipo de `Exception` e isso não é legal.
Não é legal por que significa que você não tem domínio completo das `Exception`s que podem vir do bloco `try`.

A forma correta é especializar as capturas das `Exception`s. Ex:

```
try {
    if (servico.getDiaServico().after(servico.getDiaGarantia())) {
        FacesUtil.addWarnMessage("A data do serviço, não pode ser maior do que a data da garantia.");
        throw new NegocioException("Não foi possível salvar o cliente POR PROBLEMA DE REGRA DE NEGOCIO!")
    }
    servicoDAO.salvar(servico);
} catch (DAOException e) { //partindo do principio que você tem uma Exception para a camada de DAO
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new NegocioException("Não foi possível salvar o cliente POR ALGUM PROBLEMA NA CAMADA DE DAO / BANCO DE DADOS!");
}
```